# Android XML id within fragment collection '@android:id' gives cannot resolve symbol error.

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments

I'm new.  I have an XML for fragment collection object.  In I have two text views that work perfectly.  When I try to add another in the exact same format receiving can't resolve error. 
(ie: android:id="@android:id/tvNewText").
If I add an id like a regular XML (ie: android:id="@+id/tvAnotherNewText") I cannot access it from my Fragment onCreateView.  Any help?
**fragment_collection_object.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >



<TextView
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:padding="32dp"
    android:text="Sports Bar" />
```

This works fine, but directly below it, I add a new TextView and it cannot resolve id.

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@android:id/tvNewText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Some Words" />
```

Trying to access from code below:

```
 public static class DemoObjectFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String ARG_OBJECT = "object";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_collection_object, container, false);
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText((args.getString(ARG_OBJECT)));
        ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.tvNewText)).setText("heyo");
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Here text1 works fine and as expected, but cannot resolve on tvNewText.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: `tvNewText` sounds like a custom identifier. In your TextView use `android:id="@+id/tvNewText"`, and `onCreateView` do `findViewById(R.id.tvNewText)`

Comment: That doesn't work for me, maybe because DemoObjectFragment is static.  If I leave, (TextView)rootView.find(....) then it can't find tvNewText.  Also, this idea doesn't explain why text1 works.

Comment: if it can't find it, it means the is not part of fragment_collection_object.xml

Comment: Well, this is in where my confusion lies.  I don't understand why it can find text1 but not tvNewText.  They are added exactly the same. (to the fragment_collection_object.xml)

Comment: Solved, thanks Blackbelt.  I read closer and didn't realize I still had 'android.R.id'.  I changed and it works.  I still don't understand completely why the first text view worked and not the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `android:id="@+id/tvNewText"` to resolve the error.

Comment: I tried that, but then I get a cannot resolve symbol where I am trying to access it (above)